# Remove doi and url fields while using spmpsci bibliography style

Tags: bibtex

The `\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}` is asked by the journal. However, i would like to remove the dois and urls (but keep them in the .bib file)

is there a way to remove them automatically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

If the journal requires the use of the `spmpsci` bibliography style, you are probably *not* allowed to modify the file `spmpsci.bst` (the bibliography style file) to change the behavior of the BibTeX functions `format.url` and `format.doi`.

If this hunch is correct, the only form of recourse you have, I'm afraid, is either to delete all `url` and `doi` fields from the entries in the bib file or to globally change the field names in the bib file from `url` and `doi` to, say, `url-dummy` and `doi-dummy`, respectively. This works because BibTeX blithely ignores all fields for which it can't find a predefined function.

Comment: thank you, i think it is the right way to do it

Answer (score 0):

What reference manager are you using ?

If you are using Zotero, you can follow this tutorial https://vxlabs.com/2012/06/29/removing-urls-from-zotero-bibtex-exports/, it works pretty great !

Comment: If you're using Zotero, you can have the Zotero BBT plugin do this fields renaming automatically for you.